# Haskell List in list

Tags: list, haskell, types

Hello have a problem how to make in Haskell list of user like that:

```
list = [("Frank",24,[wall, door],1),("Ann",45,[window],0),
("Claudia",44,[window, bed],2), ("Pedro"77,[wall],1)]
```

i tried this way but it not working :

```
type Home = (Homename)
type Homename = String
type Person = (Name, Age, [Home], Num)
type Name = String
type Age = Integer
type Num = Integer
list :: [Person]
list = [("Frank",24,[wall, door],1),("Ann",45,[window],0),
("Claudia",44,[window, bed],2), ("Pedro",77,[wall],1)]
```

error: Syntax error in expression (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)

Comment: There is no `;` in the code you posted. Are you sure that's the code that is producing that error?

Comment: yes its that code dont know why he saying about ";"

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: try to make the question more clear as it's not very descriptive

Comment: The `;` error might arise if you are using an ancient Haskell compiler (please tell me that you are not running "Hugs" from 1998 :-) ) because the line starting with `("Claudia",44.....` should be indented more than the previous line. Since it's as indented as the previous line, it actually starts a new definition "as if a `;` separator was between those lines". Modern GHC does not mention the implied `;`, since that's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Strings must be in "string".
Also, you can't name a type as **Num** , it's already reserved words in **Prelude**

you may rename it to **Numb**.

```
type Home = (Homename)
type Homename = String
type Person = (Name, Age, [Home], Numb)
type Name = String
type Age = Integer
type Numb = Integer
list :: [Person]
list = [("Frank"  ,24,["wall", "door"],1),
        ("Ann"    ,45,["window"],0),
        ("Claudia",44,["window", "bed"],2),
        ("Pedro"  ,77,["wall"],1)]
```

you also need to make the body of the function start after the header in all the lines.

this will give you an error as the second line starts at position 0 as the header.

```
list :: [Person]
list = [("Frank"  ,24,["wall", "door"],1),
("Ann"    ,45,["window"],0),
("Claudia",44,["window", "bed"],2),
("Pedro"  ,77,["wall"],1)]
```